# webpack-dev-server build takes a long time?

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-hmr

I have such a script to run inline webpack-dev-server:

```
  webpack-dev-server --hot --devtool eval-source-map --output-pathinfo --watch --colors --progress  --inline --content-base public --port 8050 --host 0.0.0.0
```

Initial build takes a long time to pull all core packages and it is ok. Unfortunately any change in any react component takes a while. Is it any way to avoid building of react, react mdl and other core components similar to loaders exclude functionality?

Thank you!

Comment: Take a look at https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#devtool pick the one that better suits you.

Comment: Thx, I tried these settings. I am afraid that babel rebuild the whole package including react, react-mdl, etc. But thanks for your answer.